# System Header Files in C

Tags: c, winapi, header-files, dde

I would like to use the ddeml.h system header file in C using Code::Blocks.  When I run my program, I get errors in the system header! One of the errors says "unknown type name HDDEDATA".

I really don't have much code written.  I just started on this project.  I am trying to automate something in my lab.  I would like to use C to communicate with DDE Server.  Here is an example from the manual.  I am assuming that I would have to include in the C Code #include .  Thanks for your help!

Example
The following code fragment shows how to send a command to the Nucleus DDE
Server. It uses the Windows API DdeClientTransaction() to send a :move:relative
command.

```
// The following code fragment uses Windows DDEML APIs
// to send a move command to the Nucleus DDE Server
// and receives a status string.
//
// Variables and initial values.
HCONV hConv = NULL;
DDE Server always returns responses
Client terminates DDE Server conversations
Communications Protocols • 19
DWORD idInst = 0;
HSZ hszService = NULL;
HSZ hszTopic = NULL;
HSZ hszCmd = NULL;
BOOL err = FALSE;
HDDEDATA transResult = NULL;
DWORD dwResult = 0;
char result[300];
// Need long timeout value to allow the station to move and
// respond.
const long TIMEOUT = 60000;
// Initialize the DDEML environment. Create an Instance
// that is used in many other calls to DDE.
if(DMLERR_NO_ERROR != DdeInitialize(&idInst,MyDDECallBack,
APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0))
err = true;
// Create String handles for the server name, topic and item.
if(!err)
{
hszService = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, "EDMAIN",
CP_WINANSI);
hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, "CMI Commands",
CP_WINANSI);
hszCmd = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst,
":MOVE:REL 2 100 100 NONE",
CP_WINANSI);
err = (hszService == NULL || hszTopic == NULL ||
hszCmd == NULL);
}
// Connect to the Nucleus DDE Server. (Open a conversation).
// Captain Picard would say, "Open a channel Mr. Wharf".
if(!err)
{
hConv = DdeConnect(idInst, hszService, hszTopic, NULL);
err = hConv == NULL;
if(err)
MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to make DDE connection.\n"
"Make sure Nucleus is running.",
"DDE CLIENT ERROR", MB_ICONSTOP);
}
// Send the command string to the server.
if (!err)
{
transResult = DdeClientTransaction(NULL, 0, hConv, hszCmd,
CF_TEXT, XTYP_REQUEST, TIMEOUT, NULL);
// Read the result string. TransResult will be a
// valid data handle if the client transaction above
// was successful, and NULL if it was not. This must be
// checked since calls to DdeGetData with a NULL handle
// cause GPF’s.
20 • Nucleus 4 Communications Guide
if(transResult)
DdeGetData(transResult, (LPBYTE)result,
sizeof(result), 0);
// Display the result string.
MessageBox(NULL, result,
"RESULT", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
// Close the conversation.
if (hConv != NULL)
DdeDisconnect( hConv );
// Delete the string handles.
if ((hszService != NULL) & (idInst != NULL))
DdeFreeStringHandle( idInst, hszService );
if ((hszTopic != NULL) & (idInst != NULL))
DdeFreeStringHandle( idInst, hszTopic );
if ((hszCmd != NULL) & (idInst != NULL))
DdeFreeStringHandle( idInst, hszCmd );
// Clear out the DDEML environment.
if (idInst != NULL)
DdeUninitialize(idInst);
..
// Since we are only doing requests from Nucleus, we don’t
// expect to get callbacks to this routine. Nevertheless,
// it is necessary to create a routine with no action.
HDDEDATA CALLBACK MyDDECallBack( UINT wType,
UINT wFmt, HCONV HConv, HSZ dataHandle1, HSZ dataHandle2,
HDDEDATA data, DWORD myword1, DWORD myword2)
{
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: **...and where is the code!!!!**

Comment: Headers can contain errors, too. And poorly implemented ones might assume you've already included another header that it needs, which mightbe the case here.  But, you really need to give more context to get a useful answer.

Comment: I am using Windows XP :)

Comment: Take a look in the header file; is there a HDDEDATA type defined? I am guessing the answer is "no". Maybe this is because of certain (compiler) flags, or because it is defined elsewhere.

Comment: `Ddeml.h` (include `Windows.h`)

Comment: To expand on what BLUEPIXY touched upon: The documentation for [`DdeInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648757.aspx) has a section towards the bottom that lists the header where the API is declared, and - if it is different - the header to include. In this case the API is declared in `Ddeml.h` but you need to `#include <Windows.h>` to use it.

Comment: Thank you everyone and especially BLUEPIXY!  I got it to work by adding include Windows.h!  May I ask why I have to include it?

Comment: You need to include Windows.h because Ddeml.h uses some types that are defined in Windows.h.

Comment: @NatalieCranston: Please don't edit your question to ask new and unrelated questions. If you have new questions, just open a new question in the usual way.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, thank you!